# What's the difference between functional component and create component using useMemo() in React

Tags: reactjs

are these two method of component construction the same?

```
const myComp=(props)=><h1>props.text</h1>
```

vs

```
const myComp=useMemo((props)=><h1>props.text</h1>)
```

they both renders on props change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

- Using `useMemo` without dependency array will do nothing.
- Generally speaking, don't use `useMemo` to define components.
- To make sure you are using `useMemo` correctly, set up your linter like [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

**Long answer:**

A couple of things first:

Note that `useMemo` can only be used within another component or hook (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)) so I'll assume that for the rest of the answer.

I'd say your usage of `useMemo` is incorrect. If you want to define a component with it (however you probably shouldn't) it could be like this:

```
  const MyComp = useMemo(
    () => (props) => (
      <h1>
        {props.text}
      </h1>
    ),[]
  );
```

This defines a functional component and redefines it whenever the dependencies change. (Here the dependencies are `[]`, so it will be defined only once). Note that using `useMemo` without a dependency array will result in a linting error (`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`) if you set up your linting correctly as suggested [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

If you insist on leaving out the dependency array, `useMemo` will do nothing.

To play around a little bit with different scenarios, take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-star-9w5vk?file=/src/App.js)

```
  const MyCompA = (props) => (
    <h1>
      {props.text}
      {counter}
    </h1>
  );

  // Equivalent to MyCompA. Gives linting error
  const MyCompB = useMemo(() => (props) => (
    <h1>
      {props.text}
      {counter}
    </h1>
  ));

  // Will only be defined once and not notice changes to counter. Gives linting error
  const MyCompC = useMemo(
    () => (props) => (
      <h1>
        {props.text}
        {counter}
      </h1>
    ),
    []
  );

  // Will notice changes to counter. But generally, this  is not
  // much better than MyCompA
  const MyCompD = useMemo(
    () => (props) => (
      <h1>
        {props.text}
        {counter}
      </h1>
    ),
    [counter]
  );
```

`MyCompA` and `MyCompB` do the same thing, because `MyCompB` uses `useMemo` without dependencies. `MyCompC` uses that state `counter` but doesn't recognize changes, because it's not in the dependency array. `MyCompC` recognizes that changes, but overall is not much better than `MyCompA`.

Note the whole example is for "playing-around purpose" only so we can inspect how `useMemo` behaves. Generally speaking, defining components with `useMemo` is probably not the way to go. For that example, better use a regular component that takes both `text` and `counter` as props.

Comment: can i say defining comp with useMemo(()=>..,[]) is identical to just a pure function comp defining

Comment: No. As you can see in the codesandbox, `MyCompC` is behaving differently than `MyCompA` when you change the counter state. (by clicking on the button). `useMemo` makes `MyCompC` not recognize that state change.

Comment: Understood that now as counter is not in the watch list, function get memorised. wonderful test ground and answer. Thank you so much.  These are inner component defined within component, quite a rare case.  But i see you point of putting all these test cases up.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that the whole `useMemo` thing only works within other components. If you want to define "fresh" non-nested components, `useMemo` won't work anyway. The linter will also tell you that

Answer (score 1):

`useMemo` doesn't affect function calls and the way a component reacts to prop changes in this case. This could be achieved with `useCallback` but it's not recommended; this is what `memo` component is for.

Considering that both are defined inside component function, the one without `useMemo` will be a new component on each render and so will be remounted, while the one with `useMemo` will behave as expected.

Since the component doesn't rely on the scope in which it's defined (it's not a good practice), it shouldn't be defined inside another component and therefore won't benefit from the use of `useMemo`.